# Sequences of consecutive "fair" positive integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Ok so here is a question I thought of (while trying to solve some numbers inequalities of course):

**Definition:** We will call a number $n$ "fair" if for all $p$ prime numbers such that $v_p(n)=\alpha$:
$p^\alpha< \sqrt n$.
$v_p(n)$ is the normal notation for the max power of $p$ that divides $n$.
(That is, there is no majority for one type of primes.)
**Show (or disprove):** that $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}:$ there exist k consecutive fair numbers.
**Remark:** I tried using some density arguments but with no luck. I won't write this because it's a long proof but looking only at the density of "fair"s that their primes factorization is $pqr$ for some primes, yields density $0$ but really by a whisker (I was using some basic Stirling stuff).
And also I should mention that when I'm talking about density I'm looking at it on all the consecutive sets: $[1,n],[n+1,2n]\ldots$

Comment: What is $v_p$??

Comment: $\nu_p(n)$ is the exponent on $p$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: Added that to the question. Thank you.

Comment: Not even all of the numbers of the form $pqr$ are fair. $30=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$ and $70=2\cdot 5\cdot 7$ are fair but $42=2\cdot 3\cdot 7$ isn't. Have you done any numerical tests? For example, what are the smallest two consecutive fair numbers? The smallest three?

Comment: Sorry I meant fairs that are of this form.

Comment: Also I should say finding examples for small numbers shouldn't be hard but it's exponentialy growing (I stumbled across this while trying to prove the theorem).

Comment: Title: I only see "fair" numbers, but no justice.

Comment: It seems that fair numbers are related to this sequence: https://oeis.org/A056954 . All fair numbers appear here, only $144$ is not fair

Comment: You should probably make your title reflect the question.

Comment: @Crostul, Fix if I'm wrong but $2\cdot 5\cdot 7$ and even numbers like $, 2^2\cdot 3\cdot 7, 3^2\cdot 2\cdot 7, 2^2\cdot 5\cdot 7$ are not in this sequence. On the other hand, i do agree that only 144,240 and 540 don't seem to appear very fair.

Comment: $1553157752$ to $1553157766$ form $15$ consecutive fair positive integers. It is my personal current record holder and upto this point, there is no other sequence with length $15$ or moe.